Starting the desktop app again results in not being able to use port 7200
I was running graphdb desktop successfully, but when I went back to try to run it again it failed because it said port 7200 was in use.  But opening http:localhost:7200 shows nothing is running
I don't know what to try and I can't see where the example directory is located.

It is a quirk of TCP that a port remains "reserved" for a while after it is closed, until a timeout.  The application can set the SO_REUSEPORT socket flag to avoid that, but if you don't have the source, that's a bit hard to do.

I'm not sure what is your OS, but in Linux you can see what is using the port:
sudo netstat -lp | grep 7200
The examples can be found in the distribution directory. You can locate it with "Open disk directory" button in the GraphDB application main window.
